# angular js text to speech conversion api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, text-to-speech

Have anybody used an angular js API to convert text to speech (that is browser independent too? 
I'm currently using google chromes functionality to implement my text to speech functionality, i need to replace it with angular js.

My intention is that my app speaks out "three" "two" "one" for a particular functionality based on a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [pjTextToSpeech](http://tts.peterjurkovic.com/) module.